# Clicking mobile menu bar selects whole navbar instead of pressing button Bootstrap theme involved

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

When I try to open the menu on mobile, it does not open and instead, you just select the whole menu bar. It looks like this on the actual website: menu after being clicked on (clicked on the actual button in the right corner).

Meanwhile, this is the relevant code from the `navbar.php`:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class='container'>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" id='navbar-toggle' class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="brand">
                <a href=""><img src="assets/img/logo.svg" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="services">Services</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="contact" class="book">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Also, not sure if it makes a difference although the PHP file is named `navbar.inc.php`. And also, I'm not sure if it has to do anything with the `jquery.js` file.

Comment: What is the bootstrap's version that you use? Can you also provide us all the libraries that you've import in your project?

Comment: I don't really know how to check the version as it does not say in the bootstrap.css file. Also, I don't have bootstrap downloaded on my computer

Comment: Go in your bootstrap.css file and you will see the version on the top of the file (In comment). After that, go on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/ and be sure you've imported all the scripts and css libraries for you version of bootstrap.

Comment: ok I will import all the scripts but it does not say the bootstrap version